# ISBN-13 in bibtex

Tags: bibtex, pdftex

What is the proper way to put an ISBN-13 number into a bibtex entry?

What do I have to do to make it show up in the bibliography?

I have the following book:

```
Landmarks of Tomorrow: A Report on the New Paperback
January 1, 1996
by Peter Drucker
Paperback: 270 pages
Publisher: Transaction Publishers (January 1, 1996)
Language: English
ISBN-10: 1560006226
ISBN-13: 978-1560006220
Product Dimensions: 6.3 x 9.2 inches
Shipping Weight: 1 pounds
```

I am building a bibtex database and am expecting in the long term to track ISBN-13 numbers as the publishing industry switches over (...any decade now...).   I am curious how the proper way to store these numbers would be.

My current bibtex entry is:

```
@book{drucker1959landmarks,
  title={Landmarks of Tomorrow: A Report on the New},
  author={Drucker, Peter},
  publisher={Transaction Publishers},
  year={1996},
  ISBN={1560006226},
  note={[original edition 1959]}
}
```

I suppose the new entry might be `ISBN-13` or `ISBN13` but I am looking for precidence on how to enter this.

Comment: It would be great if you could show us a use-case via a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). Specifically, this should highlight any bibliography-related packages you may be using.

Comment: Hope my additions to the question clarify the use case.  I don't have any particular packages at this point, really just wanting advice on the best way to do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Standard `bibtex` styles cover only one type of ISBN (it does not matter if you use the 13 or 10 digit format).

With `biblatex` you can create new fields for `bibtex` entries, let us say `ISBN13` and `ISBN10`. Then all you have to do is redefine how the `isbn` field is printed, e.g.,

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{isbn}{\textsc{isbn}~\printfield{isbn13}}
```

or you can create option switches or whatever your need.

The MWE below illustrates how to create the fields and redefine the `isbn` field.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[isbn=true]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{drucker1959landmarks,
  title={Landmarks of Tomorrow: A Report on the New},
  author={Drucker, Peter},
  publisher={Transaction Publishers},
  year={1996},
  isbn={1560006226},
  ISBN10={1560006226},
  ISBN13={978-1560006220},
  note={[original edition 1959]}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{isbn10,isbn13}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[book]{isbn10,isbn13}
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareFieldFormat{isbn}{\textsc{isbn-13}~\printfield{isbn13}, \textsc{isbn-10}~\printfield{isbn10}}

\title{title}
\author{A.U. Thor}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. I would further make `10` and `13` sub-,superscript, or any other visual marker to distinguish from the following numbers.

Comment: It is important to note that the `isbn` field needs to be declared in the `book` entry. Otherwise, neither `isbn10` nor `isbn13` will be printed.