# Invalid ISBN in value of field 'isbn' (-1)

Tags: biblatex, biber, warnings

I have a little problem with `biber`. When I run it with `--validate_datamodel`, it warns me

> WARN - Datamodel: Entry 'unep2016' (mybibfile.bib): Invalid ISBN in value of field 'isbn' (-1)

As "[it does not matter if you use the 13 or 10 digit format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191837/isbn-13-in-bibtex)" (Guido), the warning must come from somewhere else. I have tried the ISBN as `9789280735806` and with hyphens in different places, e.g. `978-9280-7358-06`. Here's the bib entry:

```
@book{unep2016,
location = {Nairobi},
author = {UNEP},
publisher = {United Nations Environment Programme},
isbn = {9789280735806},
title = {{Marine Plastic debris and microplastics - Global lessons and research to inspire action and guide policy change}},
year = {2016}
}
```

Comment: https://www.isbn-check.de/checkisbn.pl?isbn=9789280735806&submit=test&lang=en says that `9789280735806` is not a correct ISBN, so does http://formvalidation.io/validators/isbn/

Comment: That ISBN is invalid; the final digit should be 2, according to http://www.hahnlibrary.net/libraries/isbncalc.html and, indeed, if I input `9789280735802` in https://www.isbn-check.com, I get a pointer to that book.

Comment: The world of TeX will never stop to amaze me. Biber checks for validity in ISBNs!? Who had the idea to implement ISBN validation. This just blows all my minds!

Comment: Just downloaded a copy of the report and the copyright page indeed indicates `978-92-807-3580-6`, but the final digit should be a `2` to pass vlaidation.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39719/calculating-checksum

Comment: Specific history for ISBN validation in Biber: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/273669/35864

Comment: I know, right!? Those bastards at UNEP can't even get the ISBN of their own publication right! :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Biber does not only check the datamodel integrity, it also explicitly checks ISBNs for validity when in `--validate_datamodel` mode. [As it turns out `978-92-807-3580-6` (`9789280735806`) as indicated on the report's copyright page is not a valid ISBN](https://tools.wmflabs.org/isbn/IsbnCheckAndFormat/IsbnCheckAndFormat?ISBN=978-92-807-3580-6) Most likely the last digit (the check digit) should be a `2` instead.

ISBN validation was implemented following discussions in [Automatically validate and format ISBNs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/273669/35864). With `--isbn-normalise` you can get hyphens in the right place even if they are missing in the `.bib` file. `--isbn13` forces 13-digit ISBNs, `--isbn10` the old 10-digit format.